# Derivation of Likelihood of SAR

Tags: bayesian, likelihood, spatial, autoregressive

It is currently puzzling to me, how to derive the likelihood function of the **Spatial Autoregressive Model**. When considering the following model

$$y=\rho Wy + Z\delta + \epsilon$$
with $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2I_n)$, I can rewrite the model to get

$$y=(I_n - \rho W)^{-1}Z\delta + (I_n - \rho W)^{-1}\epsilon$$
$$\epsilon = y-\rho Wy - Z\delta$$

and now I am struggling with the likelihood function, which looks as follows

$$L \propto (\sigma^2)^{-n/2}|I_n - \rho W|^{1/2}exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\epsilon'\epsilon)$$

but actually I don't know from where the term $|I_n - \rho W|^{1/2}$ comes from. Can someone elaborate on this derivation a little bit?

Comment: Hi: Notice that that likelihood is a function of the residuals rather than $y$ itself. The steps for obtaining it  are that, you first obtain the likelihood for $y$ and then use the jacobian to obtain the likeihood for the residuals. So, that term comes from the derivative of $\epsilon$ with respect to $y$. Some of this "obtaining of likelihoods of models" material is well described in harvey's "economic analysis of time series" if you can get your hands on that book. I hope this helped some.